# Как заставить отображать несколько элементов DIV в одну строку?

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Здравствуйте.
Есть тэг `DIV` шириной на всю страницу. Внутри него несколько таких же тегов фиксированной ширины. мне надо, чтобы все теги внутри главного отображались в строку, даже если внутренние элементы выходят за границы ширины головного тэга `DIV`. В документе большое множество стилей и, видимо, что-то мешает нужному мне отображению. Вопрос: *КАК мне заставить внутренние тэги отображаться в строку, даже если они выходят за пределы головного?*
**PS**
Мне надо только `CSS`-стиль, который заставит отображаться тэги так, как мне надо. Полностью уничтожить все родительские стили неприменимо в моей ситуации. Также можно использовать приемы `HTML5`, `CSS3` и, стало быть, могут мешать правильному отображению какие-то из стилей `CSS3`

Вот пример:

```
<div style="padding:10px 5px 5px 5px;">
    <div class="node" style="background:url(../../resources/img_friend_profile/phone.png); width: 180px;margin: 5px;">26</div>
    <div class="node x-item-selected" style="background:url(../../resources/img_friend_profile/phone.png); width: 180px; margin: 5px !important;">26</div>
    <div class="node" style="background:url(../../resources/img_friend_profile/phone.png); width: 180px">26</div>
</div>
```

Еще для более полной ясности, покажу картинку в отладчике

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

```
display: inline-block;
```

или

```
float: left;
```

Кстати inline-block в старых браузерах (firefox2; ie6,7) применяется только для встроенных элементов, с блочными элементами работает некорректно.

Comment: Спасибо! `display: inline-block;` НЕ помогло, а вот с `float: left;` прекрасно!

Answer (score 3):

Выставьте всем свойство: **display:inline-block**

Answer (score 1):

пропиши в родительский div display:flex